# How to force parallelization of tests on Azure+Nunit?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, nunit, vstest, nunittestadapter

We are setuping our current solution on azure devops.

We have a big bunch of tests(some unit tests, some integrations tests) all running with NUnit.

We have configured the test like this:

```
- task: VSTest@2
    timeoutInMinutes: 600
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '.Test.dll'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: false
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      rerunFailedTests: false
      pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35'
      minimumExpectedTests: 1000
      runInParallel: true
      distributionBatchType: basedOnAssembly
      failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
      resultsFolder: 'testResults'
```

It's working, but it's taking ages(I'm speaking of 5+ hours), and I'm searching for way to speed things up.

One weird thing: Even with the `runInParallel: true`, there is only one process(testhost) running, and consuming like 3-6% of the CPU.

What should I do to hurt my system CPU/hard disk/... and improve my test speeds?

Comment: Do you run these test on self hosted agent?

Comment: `runInParallerl` override MaxCpuCount what does `typically, a value of 0 indicates that up to all of the available free cores may be used.`

Comment: How many test assemblies are you running?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej yes, I forgot to mention that, it's on a self hosted agent.

Comment: @Charlie around 20,why?

Comment: How many cores does your proc have?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej it depends, we have several agents, one has 6 core and 12 logical processor. Another one has 4 core and 4 logical processor

Comment: Not all test code that has been written can be performed in a parallel and safe manner, so you could try to check whether your assembly meets the conditions and How about the result when you execute this test in your local in a parallel, check if it work.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/parallel-test-execution/

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT We have more than 6000 units tests, and even I agree that inside one particular assembly, we might have some cases that needs the same ressource system(and therefore are not able to be performed in a parallel manner), most of them are only testing one class of our code and you could even run 10x the same instance of test. I've read your article, but I can't find what should be helpfull about why it doesn't run in parallel?

Comment: @J4N, Yes, This is weird, I checked your settings and everything seems to be ok. Have you tested it locally without Azure devops?